# How to validate table field with information from different table using sql.alchemy.orm.validates?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Imagine I have 2 tables `Person` and `Group`. There is a relationship between these 2 tables. A `Person` has a `nickname` and that `nickname` needs to be unique in the `Group` that `Person` is linked to. How would I write `validate_nickname` for the `Person` table?

I wanted to collect every `nickname` of `Person` belonging to the `Group` that the `Person` being added belongs to and verify if the `nickname` being added already exists. I'm just not sure how to query every `Person` as I don't have access to any `SQLAlchemy.Session` inside `validate_nickname`.

Small toy example:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import validates, relationship

class Group(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'group'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    nickname = Column(String)
    group = relationship("Group", uselist=False)

    @validates('nickname')
    def validate_nickname(self, key, nickname):
        # collect nickname from every Person with group == group of person being added
        # check if nickname of person being added does not exist in list generated above
        # raise an exception in case the nickname already exists
        return address
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, can a `Person` only belong to 1 `Group`? How are they associated in the database? Your relationship configuration hints at this being the case.

Comment: I read *"verify if the nickname being added already exists"* using the dictionary definition and got "confirm that the nickname already exists in the group" whereas it seems that you want to do the opposite.

Comment: @IljaEverilä yes, in this example a person can only belong to a single group.

Comment: In that case you could just include group reference in `Person` and make `group_id, nickname` unique in order to enforce the fact in the DB.

Comment: @IljaEverilä based on your answer I did some research and edited my example. Do you think it will work if I defined `Person` like it is now?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Sorry if my English is a bit confusing. I will rephrase what I intended to convey. I want to avoid adding a duplicate nickname for the same group. This means there can still exist 2 different `Person` with the same nickname but only if they belong to different groups.

Comment: Other than that `Group.id` and `Person.group_id` have a type mismatch, looks good to me :) If you find that it works for you, maybe consider posting a self answer? (Also, the `uselist=False` is now redundant, SQLA can infer that it's a many-to-one relationship, and `__tableargs__` => `__table_args__`.)

Comment: @IljaEverilä thanks this was what I was looking for as a solution. I'm just not sure how this would work if the nickname turns into an array of nicknames and I want to make sure not duplicate nicknames are added to that group. I'm not sure this would even work with unique constraints. But I should open a new question for this right?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @IljaEverilä for the answer. I added a `group_id` foreign key to `Person` (which I forgot to add in the example) and added a UniqueConstraint with `group_id` and `name` to `__table_args__`.

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import validates, relationship
from sqlalchemy.schema import UniqueConstraint

class Group(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'group'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'
    __table_args__ = (
        UniqueConstraint('group_id', 'nickname', name='_group_id_nickname_uc'),
    )
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    nickname = Column(String)

    group_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('group.id'))
    group = relationship("Group")
```